# Replacing string value in 2D char* array c/java jni

Tags: java, c, arrays, string

I'm trying to replace a string value in a 5x5 2D char* array in c. I have managed to replace the value at the right position but for some reason the replacement char in the array is always a 'p', instead of the desired character. I have tried using strcpy() and strcat() as an alternative to assigning the value, sadly though those two methods cause a segmentation fault. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Code is attached below.

The 2D array in question looks like:

```
char *map[5][5] = {
              {".", ".", ".", ".", "."},
              {".", ".", ".", ".", "."},
              {".", ".", "G", ".", "."},
              {".", ".", ".", ".", "."},
              {".", ".", ".", ".", "."} };
```

And the method I am using to change the character at a specific position is:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MapJNI_replaceTile(JNIEnv *env, jobject jObject, jint x, jint y, jchar tile){
             char tileChar = (char)tile;
             map[y][x] = &tileChar;
    }
```

The tile is passed from a Java class.

Comment: Why the `*char[][]` instead of `char[][]`

Comment: 1. The problem I see is that you're using a pointer of a pointer of a pointer: char *map[5][5].
2. You want the code in C, yet you're using JNDI, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, `map[y][x] = &tileChar;` is bad code as once the function ends, `map[y][x]` contains an invalid pointer

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MapJNI_replaceTile(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject jObject, jint x, jint y, jchar tile){
  char tileChar = (char)tile;
  map[y][x] = &tileChar;  // BAD
}
```

---

Initialize the `map`, not a pointers, but as a 5x5 array  of `char[2]`

```
char map[5][5][2] = {
          {".", ".", ".", ".", "."},
          {".", ".", ".", ".", "."},
          {".", ".", "G", ".", "."},
          {".", ".", ".", ".", "."},
          {".", ".", ".", ".", "."} };
```

Then simply assign the first `char`.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MapJNI_replaceTile(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject jObject, jint x, jint y, jchar tile){
  char tileChar = (char)tile;
  map[y][x][0] = tileChar;
}
```

---

Alliteratively, just use a 5x5 array of `char`  [@Sniper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43475179/replacing-string-value-in-2d-char-array-c-java-jni/43475620#comment74005685_43475179).  This will impact the rest of OP's code though.

```
char map[5][5] = {
      {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.'}, 
      {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
      {'.', '.', 'G', '.', '.'},
      {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
      {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.'} };

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MapJNI_replaceTile(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject jObject, jint x, jint y, jchar tile){
  char tileChar = (char)tile;
  map[y][x] = tileChar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You are passing the address of the tileChar, I think you want to pass
>   the char itself.
>
> ```
> map[y][x] = tileChar;
> ```

**EDIT:** did not notice it was an array of pointers, ignore what I said above.

you are creating a char in the stack, so when you are returning from the function the pointer to the char you created is no longer valid. you will need to create the char in the heap.

Comment: Declaring the tileChar in the heap worked perfectly. Thanks!